# Minimum example of async/await throwing "The calling thread cannot access this object because a different thread owns it."

Tags: c#, asynchronous

I have gone over documentation and various examples but they all discuss things in the context of UI.

I understand that objects owned by a particular thread cannot be accessed by a different thread. However, in my case, I don't see how this is applicable (but of course, I am doing it *somehow*, I just can't pintpoint it).

The code I am working on is quite complex and I am unable to reproduce a minimum working example.

What I would like to see is a **minimum working example of using `async` and `await` where this exception is thrown** as I am unable to find one.

Comment: Are you using `ConfigureAwait(false)` on your async calls? That will open up the possibility of the method continuing to execute NOT on the context thread.

Comment: @Andy no I am not

Answer (score 0, accepted):

From [Async/Await - Best Practices in Asynchronous Programming](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/magazine/jj991977.aspx?f=255&MSPPError=-2147217396)

```
async Task MyMethodAsync()
{
  // Code here runs in the original context.
  await Task.Delay(1000);
  // Code here runs in the original context.
  await Task.Delay(1000).ConfigureAwait(
    continueOnCapturedContext: false);
  // Code here runs without the original context (in this case, on the thread pool).

  ////////////////
  // ETA: Put some UI code here and it will probably throw an exception.
}
```

Here is another example to get an exception:

```
await Task.Run(()=>{ /* place your UI code here */});
```

Comment: It may or may not -- It is up to the runtime to return ownership back to the context thread. That's why i wrote "probably". I don't know the logic to force it off the context thread from `ConfigureAwait`.

Comment: Thank you @Andy. Your example makes sense. Even though it's not directly applicable in my case, your example gives me something to think about.

Comment: I added another example